# Float anywhere in the book in any order to use the leftover white space

Tags: floats

I have a few dozen uncaptioned floats containing text of different lengths in a `\book` of 50-100 pages containing a dozen chapters or so. I would like the floats to:

1. float anywhere in the book,
2. in any order wherever there is a bad page break that left white space that needs filling and
3. using one float only on a page.
4. If there are unused floats after all the filling, that's fine too. This is somewhat like the short filler jokes/stories you find in magazines.

Here is one:

```latex
    \fbox{\parbox{\linewidth}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.}}
```

I have tried several options:-

1. Put float before a chapter - Then they get a page of their own
2. Put float at the beginning of the chapter - Floats are placed at the beginning of the chapter
3. Put float at the end of the chapter - Floats are placed at the end of the chapter

What I'd like instead to happen is that floats get picked up out of order based on the available space left at the end of any chapter not just the current.

Is that even possible? Are there alternative document classes I am missing? Should I do away with `\chapter`s?

Comment: latex doesn't support this without quite some additional work. Also you should say if you want numbered captions, standard captions are set when the float is saved so re-numbering at point of use would require different mechanisms.

Comment: you would also need to say what criterion is used for adding floats, if you have 100 possible floats of average say 25% of page height do you add 3 or 4 every page until  they run out or add one each page, or only add one if there is a bad page break leaving white space that needs filling or .... do you need to use all the supplied imges, or only enough to pad spaces?

Comment: Thanks. Edited. The boxes are uncaptioned. And the criteria is "fill the bad page breaks".

Comment: You could say at the end of each chapter, "if last paragraph ended at < 2/3 textheight, insert (next) xn at page bottom", where n=a counter (?chapter number??) - like a vignette. And not use any floating.

Comment: You do not show an example of a float (usually a `figure` or `table` environment). Are you actually using floats? Provide an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we can compile that shows your problem.To have no more than one float on a page specify `\setcounter{totalnumber}{1}` Why not just put the fdloats in your document in the order you want them to appear and let LaTeX fill up any spaces?